# another way to solve this without using document.write()

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript and wondering if there's another way of doing this without the use of document.write()

```
    <script>
      for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
        document.write("<div class='menu'>");
        document.write("<button id='btn"+i+"' value='"+i * 10+"'>");
        document.write("<img class='screen_icon' src='./assets/img/screen.png'>");
        document.write("<span class='screenSource'>None</span>");
        document.write("<span class='screen_text'>Screen "+i+"</span>");
        document.write("</button>");
        document.write("</div>");
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can append the div to the parent container

```
for (var i = 0; i < =2; i++) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = "<div class='menu'>" +
        "<button id='btn"+i+"' value='"+i * 10+"'>" +
        "<img class='screen_icon' src='./assets/img/screen.png'>" + '
        "<span class='screenSource'>None</span>" +
        "<span class='screen_text'>Screen "+i+"</span>" +
        "</button>"+
        "</div>"
      document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(div);
    }
```

Comment: Adding to the above; the invention of [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). They support line breaks, so no more adding plus signs on the end of each line and variables can be included like so ```<span class='screen_text'>Screen ${i}</span>``` or so ```<button id='btn${i}' value='${(i * 10)}'>```.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers , and pointing me in the right direction.

Ended up with this code that you suggested, with a little modification.

```
   for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.innerHTML = "<button id='btn"+i+"' value='"+i * 10+"'>" +
           "<img class='screen_icon' src='./assets/img/screen.png'>" +
           "<span class='screenSource'>None</span>" +
           "<span class='screen_text'>Screen "+i+"</span>" +
           "</button>";
       document.getElementById('main_menu').appendChild(div);
       div.classList.add("menu");
   };
```